# Missing $ inserted when using custom math symbol

Tags: macros

I defined a command:

```
\newcommand{\lequiv}{\raisebox{-0.25 \height}{\overset{<}{\sim}}}
```

But whenever I try to use it (for instance, in `gather`, I get `Missing $ inserted`. Why?

Comment: Because `\raisebox` switches to text mode. Just change to `\newcommand{\lequiv}{\raisebox{-0.25 \height}{$\overset{<}{\sim}$}}`

Comment: although the question as stated is answered well, the symbol you are trying to get already exists as `\lesssim` with `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\raisebox` command is used to declare the vertical position of text; that is to lower or raise text. Note the text is processed in `LR mode` With this said,

```
\newcommand{\lequiv}{\raisebox{-0.25\height}{\overset{<}{\sim}}}
```

is incorrectly declared and gives an error because of math declarations that should be in `math mode` and which are in `text mode`.

A quick fix is to:

```
\newcommand{\lequiv}{\raisebox{-0.25\height}{$\overset{<}{\sim}$}}
```

Answer (score 3):

azetina’s answer addresses the error you get and removes it. On the other hand, the output you get is rather poor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

$A\lesssim B\le C\gtrsim D_{x\lesssim y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a better definition than your `\lequiv` that could come handy in case you want something different from `\sim`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lequiv}{\lg@equiv{<}}
\newcommand{\gequiv}{\lg@equiv{>}}
\newcommand{\lg@equiv}[1]{\mathrel{\mathpalette\lg@@equiv{#1}}}

\newcommand{\lg@@equiv}[2]{%
  \raisebox{.3\depth}{%
    \vtop{\m@th\offinterlineskip
      \ialign{##\cr$#1#2$\cr\noalign{\kern1pt}$#1{\sim}$\cr}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\lequiv B\le C\gequiv D_{x\lequiv y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A visual comparison with what you’d get with your definition.

[image]

On the other hand, `amssymb` provides `\lesssim` and `\gtrsim`:

Comment: why not just use `\lesssim` from the `amssymb` package?

Comment: Should I delete my answer? You can amend yours to reflect the problem and give the improvement.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Because I didn't remember about it!

Comment: @azetina no, keep it and add about `\lessim`

Comment: @azetina -- note that `\lesssim` has 3 esses: "less" + "sim".